# Block hover on internal elements?

Tags: html, css

Block pseudo-class "hover" on internal elements.
When hovering on an internal element, it should not work.
How to implement this?

```css
.link:hover {
  background: #499a75;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">
  Test
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
</a>
```

Comment: Please explain in better detail. You don't want the link to interact when you're hovering over 1 and 2?

Comment: First of all, your html is wrong... You have to close the a tag before opening the ul.

Comment: I don't think any browser supports `.link:hover:not(:has(li:hover))` yet.

Comment: @BalázsVarga — The point is that the `<ul>` is *inside* the `<a>`.

Comment: close the anchor tag and check.

Comment: @Quentin if the whole thing is inside tha <a> then you WILL hover the <a> tag on all elements. I think you need a javascript solution to this.

Comment: Please explain in better detail. You don't want the link to interact when you're hovering over 1 and 2? Yes

Comment: Check my answer ;)

Comment: @Balázs Varga working . There are times when you need to quickly correct mistakes, and old templates do not have time to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With javascript, you can check whether the event target is exactly the same element you want to apply the effect on. If yes, add a class, and if not, remove that.

```js
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('a.link')[0];
anchor.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverin, false);
anchor.addEventListener('mouseout', hoverout, false);

function hoverin(event) {
    if(event.target === anchor) {
        anchor.classList.add('hover');
    }
    else {
        hoverout();
    }
}

function hoverout() {
    anchor.classList.remove('hover');
}
```

```css
.link.hover {
  background: #499a75;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Test
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</a>
```